# Intellij keeps throwing ClassNotFoundExcpetion

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lwjgl

In my program I have several modules placed in different folders and all of them are dependent on a "*core*" module.

I have already setup a configuration for Intellij to run the program, but every time I try to run I receive a ClassNotFound Excpetion. I'm not sure if this is due to my core module having a similar packages i.e. com.adpetlabs.flappybird

Could the problem be related to the packages or something else? I really need help in resolving this

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adeptlabs.flappybird.desktop.DesktopLauncher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

Comment: Please share more details. is the above exception is of file from core module ?

Comment: Have you setup the dependencies between modules?

Comment: Are you using maven, or normal library depdencies (per module)?

Comment: The above exception is from the desktop module.

Comment: Yes I've setup dependencies between modules